# Как обработать исключение InputMismatchException?

Tags: java, исключения

Всем привет! У меня есть метод который отвечает за ввод с клавиатуры:

```
public int inputValue() {
        int value;

        while (true) {

            System.out.print("Введите размер таблицы от " + LEFT_BOUND + " до " + RIGHT_BOUND + ": ");
            value = scanner.nextInt();
            if (isValid(value)) {
                return value;
            }
            System.out.println("Введите корректное значение от " + LEFT_BOUND + " до " + RIGHT_BOUND + "! ");
        }
    }
```

Если я введу какие нибудь значения отличные от int то выбросится исключение, как его нормально обработать в этом цикле?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "нормально"? Как хочется, так и обрабатывайте.

Comment: Чтобы можно было вернуть значение value, т.к. не знаю как это сделать - из блоков try/catch return не работает

Comment: если ввожу int то возвращается true, иначе если ввожу хоть что то не int то false

Comment: Работает.  Почему бы ему не работать?!

Comment: все, разобрался)

Answer (score 0):

1. public String inputValue() {
           String value;

   ```
       while (true) {

           System.out.print("Введите размер таблицы от " + LEFT_BOUND + " до " + RIGHT_BOUND + ": ");
           value = scanner.nextLine();
           if (isValid(value)) {
               return value;
           }
           System.out.println("Введите корректное значение от " + LEFT_BOUND + " до " + RIGHT_BOUND + "! ");
       }
   }

   private boolean isValid(String value) { //        return value >= LEFT_BOUND && value <= RIGHT_BOUND;

       try {
           return Integer.parseInt(value)<=RIGHT_BOUND && Integer.parseInt(value)>=LEFT_BOUND;

       }catch (Exception e){
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```